# How to strip Timestamp up to just seconds?

Tags: oracle

Given a timestamp value, i.e. "04-SEP-14 03.09.09.272949000 PM", how do I get the date time up to just the seconds part and zeroing out the micro-seconds part?

given: 04-SEP-14 03.09.09.272949000 PM
wish:  04-SEP-14 03.09.09.00 PM

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `cast` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm) to cast it to a zero-millisecond TIMESTAMP with the construct:

```
cast(<your column>, timestamp(0))
```

Using a CTE to pass in your value:

```
with t as (
  select to_timestamp('04-SEP-14 03.09.09.272949000 PM',
    'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') as tstamp
  from dual
)
select to_char(cast(tstamp as timestamp(0)), 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF2 AM')
from t;

TO_CHAR(CAST(TSTAMPASTIMESTAMP(0)),'DD-M
----------------------------------------
04-SEP-14 03:09:09.00 PM
```

You could also cast it twice, once to `DATE` to strip the milliseconds, and then back to TIMESTAMP again:

```
with t as (
  select to_timestamp('04-SEP-14 03.09.09.272949000 PM',
    'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') as tstamp
  from dual
)
select to_char(cast(cast(tstamp as date) as timestamp),
  'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF2 AM')
from t;

TO_CHAR(CAST(CAST(TSTAMPASDATE)ASTIMESTA
----------------------------------------
04-SEP-14 03:09:09.00 PM
```

... which is doing more work as well as being more typing.

You can't use [`trunc(date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm) because that implicitly converts the TIMESTAMP to a DATE, and since a DATE is already at that precision you can't pass `SS` as the `fmt` anyway.